# Are there any disadvantages for doing a mutate + filter vs summarise on a grouped data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

In `dplyr 0.5.0`, calling `summarise` on a grouped data frame does not guarantee any resultant row order (Currently, it reorders the rows by group, not sure how it handles duplicate grouping levels).

To get around this, I would like to replace all `summarise(x = ...)` operations with `mutate(x = ...) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)`. Are there any disadvantages or drawbacks to doing this?

Example of the two operations.

```
tmp_df <- 
    data.frame(group = rep(c(2L, 1L), each = 5), b = rep(c(-1, 1), each = 5)) %>%
    group_by(group)

tmp_df %>%
    summarise(b = sum(b))

tmp_df %>%
    mutate(b = sum(b)) %>%
    filter(row_number() == 1)
```

producing:

```
> tmp_df %>%
+     summarise(b = sum(b))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  group     b
  <int> <dbl>
1     1     5
2     2    -5
> tmp_df %>%
+     mutate(b = sum(b)) %>%
+     filter(row_number() == 1)
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
Groups: group [2]

  group     b
  <int> <dbl>
1     2    -5
2     1     5
```

EDIT: In response to a comment, for readability I can define the function:

```
summarise_o <- function (.data, ...) {
    # order preserving summarise
    mutate_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) %>%
        filter(row_number() == 1) %>% 
        return
}
```

and simply call:

```
tmp_df %>%
    summarise_o(b = sum(b))
```

Comment: `summarize()` seems much more readable/meaningful to me, since that's what you're doing. If the row order is so important, sort afterwards.

Comment: I am willing to sacrifice readability to preserve row ordering, as down the analysis pipeline I may have already forgotten how I ordered my data frames. (In fact what I would really like is to define a new summarise function that replaces the mutate + filter).

Comment: Use a data.table: `tmp_df %>% data.table %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(b = sum(b))` shows the expected order for me. I'm loading the data.table package instead of dtplyr, but I guess it works the same. (I'm using `data.table()` instead of `setDT()` since it's more consistent with the don't-modify-stuff philosophy of dplyr.)

Comment: @Frank, neat! but I am bit scared that that works!

Comment: If the documentation doesn't specifically say it preserves order, then it could well be that `data.table` version will start doing the same thing in the next release, so be careful with it.

Comment: Yeah, I'd be scared about it being reliable. Data.table documentation *does* say explicitly that row order is preserved, but dtplyr/dplyr makes no promises, as far as the group_by/summarise interface to data.table goes, and I don't think it ever will (since that's part of the point of having a unified interface, I'm guessing).

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create the 'group' as a `factor`

```
tmp_df <- data.frame(group = rep(c(2L, 1L), each = 5), b = rep(c(-1, 1), each = 5)) %>%
             group_by(group = factor(group, levels = unique(group)))

tmp_df %>%
    summarise(b = sum(b))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#    group     b
#   <fctr> <dbl>
#1      2    -5
#2      1     5
```

Comment: this is very neat but in normal usage there may be more than one grouping variable though, i suppose you can then create a group index or something.

Comment: @Alex If there are more than one group, then `df1 %>% mutate_at(vars(colsofinterest), funs(factor(., levels = unique(.)))) %>% group_by_(.dots = colsofinterest)`